# Tool to generate TCP traffic

Tags: linux, shell-script, windows, tcp, traffic

I want to generate a TCP traffic starting from the port 0 to the port 65535. 1 tcp packet for each port with 1ms between 2 packets. The generator should not care if there is a TCP ACK or not.

1. Are there a tool that can generate a such traffic?
2. Is it possible to do that with iperf and script?
3. Ie it possible to run it on windows too?

Comment: Have you tried with `ncat` or `nmap`?

Comment: For other needs, you might consider D-ITG, the Distributed Internet Traffic Generator, from here: http://traffic.comics.unina.it/software/ITG/ .

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to accomplish that using a packet generator, I can recommend [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/), which is a packet generator library for Python. You can use it out of the box on the Python Console or script it. It should also run on Windows.

Nevertheless, as already recommended in the comments, maybe `nmap` should be sufficient to accomplish your aim. `nmap` is not really a packet generator, but should be able to send the packets you intend to send.

Answer (score 6):

You should consider [hping3](https://github.com/antirez/hping). It has plenty of [documentation](http://hping.org/documentation.php), and it will probably be able to do what you want.

Comment: you beat me to hping...  super awesome tool

Answer (score 6):

[Ostinato](https://code.google.com/p/ostinato/) aims to be "Wireshark in Reverse" and become complementary to Wireshark.
Ostinato is an open-source, cross-platform network packet crafter/traffic generator and analyzer with a friendly GUI. Craft and send packets of several streams with different protocols at different rates.